# Windows 10 upgrade failing with "Win10UpgradeProgramInChina" events in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I just tried to upgrade a Windows 7 machine to Windows 10 and it failed for no apparent reason. Both `Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant` and `Media Creation Tool` fail, the former with `0xc1900200` and latter with `0x800704DD-0x90016` error code.

When it happens (with Upgrade Assistant), the following three events appear in Event Viewer. Why are they mentioning China?! The machine is (and always was) from figgin' Central Europe and appears to meet the requirements (I do get conflicting statements from the upgrade nagger as also shown below, noticed this today, do not recall ever seeing it before).

[image]

[image]

The machine is both "Good to go" and "Unable to".

```
Fault bucket 568497307, type 29
Event Name: WinSetupDiag02
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 1
P2: 2
P3: X
P4: 3
P5: 0xC1900200
P6: 0x40008
P7: 7601
P8: win7sp1_gdr
P9: X
P10: X

Attached files:
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\diagerr.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_1_8a6ccaa215c554b926ec248ab1adcd15b9e934_083572ce

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 2cb21a52-41ef-11e6-9881-005056c00008
Report Status: 0
```

```
Fault bucket 2047321030, type 29
Event Name: Win10UpgradeProgramInChina
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 125216112230

Problem signature:
P1: Win10UpgradeChina
P2: Failed
P3: Setup execution result failed!
P4: 6.1 (7601),Service Pack 1,1, 256
P5: {E52ABFC2-76BB-4908-883F-CA581FDD83F9}
P6: -1047526912
P7: 1.4.9200.17332-[URL:9194:<1.4.9200.17332>:<1>]
P8: Undefined
P9: true
P10: Undefined

Attached files:
C:\$GetCurrent\downlevel_2016_07_04_21_49_14_168.rpt
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log
C:\$GetCurrent\Logs\downlevel_2016_07_04_21_49_14_168.log

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\NonCritical_Win10UpgradeChin_a1a3d0aaa1e724b4e6a2355b30d3e1285fdb8950_cab_048582b6

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 2ecc1150-41ef-11e6-9881-005056c00008
Report Status: 8
```

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: Win10UpgradeProgramInChina
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Win10UpgradeChina
P2: Failed
P3: Setup execution result failed!
P4: 6.1 (7601),Service Pack 1,1, 256
P5: {E52ABFC2-76BB-4908-883F-CA581FDD83F9}
P6: -1047526912
P7: 1.4.9200.17332-[URL:9194:<1.4.9200.17332>:<1>]
P8: Undefined
P9: true
P10: Undefined

Attached files:
C:\$GetCurrent\downlevel_2016_07_04_21_49_14_168.rpt
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log
C:\$GetCurrent\Logs\downlevel_2016_07_04_21_49_14_168.log

These files may be available here:


Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 2ecc1150-41ef-11e6-9881-005056c00008
Report Status: 0
```

Here's the smaller `setuperr.log`:

```
2016-07-04 15:53:47, Error                 MOUPG  CSystemHelper::CheckConnectedStandby(642): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-04 15:53:51, Error                        CDiagnosticsHelper::SetSQMDatapoint: Attempting to set a datapoint in an invalid SQM session
2016-07-04 15:53:51, Error                        CDiagnosticsHelper::SetSQMDatapoint: Attempting to set a datapoint in an invalid SQM session
2016-07-04 15:53:51, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2016-07-04 15:53:51, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(724): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-07-04 15:53:51, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(389): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-07-04 15:53:52, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(232): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-07-04 15:53:52, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(371): Result = 0x800705BB
2016-07-04 15:53:52, Error                 MOUPG  CSystemHelper::CheckConnectedStandby(642): Result = 0x80070057
2016-07-04 15:56:59, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class ICompatAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2016-07-04 15:56:59, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(730): Result = 0xC1900200
2016-07-04 15:56:59, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(389): Result = 0xC1900200
2016-07-04 15:56:59, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectNewSystem: Cannot resurrect new system.: Win32Exception: \\?\C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\NewSystem.dat: The system cannot find the file specified. [0x00000002] __cdecl UnBCL::FileStream::FileStream(const class UnBCL::String *,enum UnBCL::FileMode,enum UnBCL::FileAccess,enum UnBCL::FileShare,unsigned long)[gle=0x00000002]
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Cancel(979): Result = 0xC1800104
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class ICompatAction> > > >::CheckInitialized(228): Result = 0x8000000A
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class ICompatAction> > > >::Cancel(154): Result = 0x8000000A
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Cancel(1030): Result = 0x8000000A
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpManager::Reset(1672): Result = 0x8000000A
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  SetupManager: Reset WinDlp State failed with error [0x8000000A]
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  SetupManager: Failed requested cleanup: [0x8000000A]
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(232): Result = 0xC1900200
2016-07-04 15:57:01, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(371): Result = 0xC1900200
```

Comment: Start with what's listed here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-setup-error-0x800704dd-0x90016/0ec65f77-7878-4313-b32f-038be76380c7?auth=1, as well as performing disk checks (`chkdsk`), and then come back and edit  what you tried, and what the results were into your question.

Comment: Already did everything in that answer listed by @Techie. In addition to installing *all* available updates.

Comment: Windows 10 has a version specific for China.  Download the .ISO from the TestBench website and create a bootable USB, and from within Windows, start the upgrade.  That will be the only way it will successfully upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound, where would I check if my Windows 7 installation is China specific?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, I was able to run `Media Creation Tool` after I logged in with an admin account. It failed two times. First, due to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086249) and then due to `0xC1900101 - 0x20017`. Something appears to be seriously wrong with my Windows 7 install.

Comment: @Predi There isn't a China version of Windows 7 there is a China version of a Windows 10, my mitigation, is your solution to that problem

Comment: @Ramhound, I see. I've now managed to install it. The "China" messages were not actually relevant. Turns out the upgrade process does not like my hardware - had to pull out two of the four ram sticks during upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out those `Win10UpgradeProgramInChina` messages were not relevant to my problems at all (still can't make sense of them). While I don't know what caused `Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant` to fail, I did manage to upgrade using `Media Creation Tool` (described [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-download-official-windows-10-iso-files/35cde7ec-5b6f-481c-a02d-dadf465df326)).

The latter does not like it when you run it with a Standard User Account, despite it asking for Admin privileges. You *must* run it when logged in with an Admin account. Had I continued reading [http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/...](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-setup-error-0x800704dd-0x90016/0ec65f77-7878-4313-b32f-038be76380c7?auth=1) beyond the accepted answer (like @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 suggested), I would have easily worked around `0x800704DD-0x90016`.

I still had two further failures before the upgrade was a success. The first one was caused by not enough space on the System Reserved Partition (`0xc1900104`, "We couldn’t update system reserved partition"). The issue and solution are described in [KB3086249](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086249) and worked for me. It involved deleting some language files and truncating a log file from the partition.

Next I had a `0xC1900101 - 0x20017` which usually indicates hardware driver problems. The target machine had 20GB of RAM, which seems to have been a problem (or one of them). I removed two of the four sticks of RAM before the successful attempt (two 4GB sticks were left). I also did the following:

- I **did not** disable my antivirus protection during upgrade process (all my prior attempts were with it disabled, the antivirus was ESET Endpoint Antivirus 5.0).
- as soon as `Media Creation Tool` finished downloading the upgrade (I used "Upgrade this PC now"), I disconnected the LAN cable. I think during "Checking your computer" phase.
- I disconnected my secondary monitor (RGB cable).

Everything else was already disconnected (except USB keyboard and USB mouse) in my prior attempts.

The machine is an HP Compaq 8200 Elite Convertible Min Tower, migrated to an SSD.

<sub>(maybe this write up helps some other poor soul out there)</sub>